# Elasticsearch: sorting Spanish double names alphabetically

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, alphabetical

I am doing an Elasticsearch query and I want the results ordered alphabetically by last name. My problem: the last names are all Spanish double names, and ES doesn't order them the way I would like it. 
I would prefer the order to be:

```
Batres Rivera
Batrín Chojoj
Fion Morales
Lopez Giron
Martinez Castellanos
Milán Casanova
```

This is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "Last Name": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The order that I get with this is:

```
Batres Rivera
Batrín Chojoj
Milán Casanova
Martinez Castellanos
Fion Morales
Lopez Giron
```

So it is not sorting by the first string, but by either of both (Batres, Batrín, Casanova, Castellanos, Fion, Giron).
If I try additionally

```
{
    "order": "asc",
    "mode": "max"
}
```

then I get:

```
Batrín Chojoj
Lopez Giron
Martinez Castellanos
Milán Casanova
Fion Morales
Batres Rivera
```

All the fields are indexed by default, I checked with

```
curl -XGET localhost/my_index/_mapping
```

and I get back

```
my_index: {
    my_type: {
        properties: {
            FirstName: {
                type: string
            }LastName: {
                type: string
            }MiddleName: {
                type: string
            }
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to make the results to be ordered to be ordered alphabetically by the beginning string of the last name?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you missing anything from the answer? If not, could you accept it please?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I already did, done now. 
No, nothing missing, thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that your `LastName` field is analyzed, so the string `Batres Rivera` is indexed as a multi-value field with two terms: `batres` and `rivera`.  But this isn't like an ordered array, it's more like a "bag of values". So when you try to sort on the field, it chooses one of the terms (the `min` or `max`) and sorts on that.

What you need to do is to store the `LastName` as a single term (`Batres Rivera`) for sorting purposes, by mapping the field as

```
{ "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed"}
```

Obviously you can't then use that field for search purposes: you wouldn't be able to search for `rivera` and match on that field.

The way to support both searching and sorting is to use multi-fields: ie index the same value in two ways, one for searching and one for sorting.

In 0.90.* the syntax for multi-fields is:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index" -d'
{
   "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
         "properties": {
            "LastName": {
               "type": "multi_field",
               "fields": {
                  "LastName": {
                     "type": "string"
                  },
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

In 1.0.* the `multi_field` type has been removed and now any core field type supports sub-fields as follows:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index" -d'
{
   "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
         "properties": {
            "LastName": {
               "type": "string",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

So you can use the `LastName` field for searching, and the `LastName.raw` field for sorting:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "LastName": "rivera"
      }
   },
   "sort": "LastName.raw"
}'
```

### Language specific sorting

You should also look at using the [ICU analysis plugin](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-icu-plugin.html) to sort using the Spanish sort order (or collation). This is a bit more complex but is worth using:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index" -d'
{
   "settings": {
      "analysis": {
         "analyzer": {
            "folding": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
               "filter": [
                  "icu_folding"
               ]
            },
            "es_sorting": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "keyword",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "spanish"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter": {
            "spanish": {
               "type": "icu_collation",
               "language": "es"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
         "properties": {
            "LastName": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "folding", 
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "es_sorting"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

We create a `folding` analyzer which we'll use for the `LastName` field, which will analyze a string like `Muñoz Rivera` into the two terms `munoz` (without the `~`) and `rivera`.  So a user can search for `munoz` or `muñoz` and either will match.

Then we create the `es_sorting` analyzer which indexes the proper sort order for `muñoz rivera` (lowercased) in Spanish.

Searching would be done in the same way:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search" -d'
{
   "query": {
      "match": {
         "LastName": "rivera"
      }
   },
   "sort": "LastName.raw"
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to know how you are indexing the name.

Please check this discussion link.

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Is-there-a-way-to-search-terms-lower-cased-td932996.html

This should be very helpful for your case. This depends on your mapping settings. What analyzer you use for the name field.

Need your mapping definition to decide on a proper solution.

Comment: I haven't created a mapping beforehand.

Comment: Hm, I don't really see how this is helping me. I don't use analyzers yet. Do I have to in order to be able to sort? Also I can't go to any of the http://www.elasticsearch.com/docs/...-links, I am not a paying client.

Comment: May I know what fields you index? How did you index the documents?

Comment: I didn't specify which fields are indexed, so all the fields should be indexed by default. I checked with curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_search?pretty=1' and it gives me back all the fields, so that should work.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to update the question with the output of the following command: `curl -XGET '127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/_mapping?pretty'`

Comment: Ok I need some more info. This seems going over. Do u have any gmail id? if possible can you come into chat @ ovamsikrishnatest@gmail.com?

Comment: Well you seem to be skeptic. Not a problem. Need output of `curl -XGET '127.0.0.1:9200/my_index/my_type/<id>?pretty'` please fill in the id of document from the database in the above command and update the question.